# Texture isn't mapped to quad

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

I'm using the following to draw text in OpenGL (using SDL)

```
void renderText(const TTF_Font *font, const SDL_Color color,
                const double& x, const double& y, const double& z,  const std::string& text) {
    bool textured = glIsEnabled(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    //test color: black
    glColor3f(0,0,0);
    SDL_Surface *Message = TTF_RenderText_Blended(const_cast<TTF_Font*>(font), text.c_str(), color);
    GLuint Texture = 0;

    //Generate an OpenGL 2D texture from the SDL_Surface
    glGenTextures(1, &Texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Texture);

    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, Message->w, Message->h, 0, GL_BGRA,
                 GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, Message->pixels);

    //Draw this texture on a quad with the given xyz coordinates.
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2d(0, 0); glVertex3d(x, y, z);
        glTexCoord2d(1, 0); glVertex3d(x+Message->w, y, z);
        glTexCoord2d(1, 1); glVertex3d(x+Message->w, y+Message->h, z);
        glTexCoord2d(0, 1); glVertex3d(x, y+Message->h, z);
    glEnd();

    //Clean up
    glDeleteTextures(1, &Texture);
    SDL_FreeSurface(Message);
    if (!textured)
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

However, the only thing shown is a rectangle at *(x,y)* (in this case *(10,10)*) with the background color set with `glColor3f` (black in this case). The texture created from the SDL_Surface isn't shown on the quad. The arguments passed to the function are all valid:

```
font: previously loaded TTF_Font != NULL
color: SDL_Color {255,255,255} (white)
x = 10
y = 10
z = 0
text = "test"
```

What's wrong here?

---

- `glOrtho(0.0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0.0, -1.0, 10.0);`
- OpenGL v2.2
- SDL v1.2.15
- Kubuntu Raring x64

---

**Update**: When using ..._Solid instead of ..._Blended, calling `glColor3f(1,1,1)` and passing SDL_Color {255,255,255} results in some strange stuff:

[image]

The quad appears where it should appear, and it shows strange content. What's wrong?

Comment: `glColor3f` does not set the "background color." It sets the ***current*** color. Depending on your texture env. state, that usually means that color is multiplied by your texture to produce the final color. Obviously if you multiply something by black you get black.

Comment: yes, but this doesn't explain why I don't get any text, does it?

Comment: It explains why whatever your texture contains is not applied. You could have a full-white texture and if you multiplied it by (**0.0**, **0.0**, **0.0**) you would never know all you would see is black.

Comment: I've also tried with white, and it turns full white, the same with any other color (when the text color is white). This must mean the texture becomes fully white, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

THe problem was that I didn't call `glBlendFunc` before calling above method. So OpenGL had a wrong blending mode set. After using `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);`it looks fine.